# Templated Refactoring of Constructors For DI

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, refactoring, resharper, ninject

Apologies if this has been asked/answered before, my searches on this topic have lead me to a huge variety of topics that are not really directly related to my task here.

I currently need to accomplish the goal of refactoring a large amount constructors within an internal codebase to support constructor injection using Ninject. Currently, we have a large amount of instances of `KernelInstance.Get<T>` as getter properties, ex:

```
IRequiredService => StaticKernelReference.Get<IRequiredService>();
```

Where StaticKernelReference is a reference to a static instance of a Ninject StandardKernel (I am aware this is considered an anti-pattern as well, and this refactoring is one part of a goal to kill all static references to the Ninject instance)

In moving away from doing this approach that is apparently deemed an anti-pattern, I want to refactor those references this approach:

```
public class ClassWithDependencies {
  readonly IRequiredSevice _requiredService;
  public ClassWithDependencies(IRequiredService requiredService){
    _requiredService = requiredService;
  }
}
```

My question is really two-fold, but help with either question would be greatly appreciated.

1. Is the above example provided the ideal way to do do constructor injection of these dependencies (my research on SO and elsewhere indicates yes, but I would appreciate input if I have made an incorrect conclusion). I'm very confident that this approach is an improvement of our existing, but I would prefer to not have to do a second refactoring pass on this specific piece if this is not ideal. In most cases these will not be optional dependencies (and the reason why I'm utilizing the constructor injection pattern), and I am aware of the [Inject] decorator for property injection.
2. I tagged this question with resharper because it's the only thing that comes to mind for a large-scale refactoring like this. Is there any good approach for adding a constructor parameter, and then a code snippet/template auto-generating the assignment to the readonly private variable in the constructor and addition of a field to the class? While I could do this manually, I foresee this being quite tedious and time-consuming, since there are at least a few hundred instances of this pattern being used.

Comment: A step in the right direction. Some reading to answer part 1: http://deviq.com/explicit-dependencies-principle/ Part 2 is as a result of technical debt that is now being called in.

Comment: Glad to hear it's an improvement and yeah, I figured there is no way around fixing this without some tedious refactoring. Thank you for your feedback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes this approach is fine. Injecting required dependencies to constructor makes them explicit and visible. Right now to figure out dependencies of your class you have no other choice than inspecting its source code. When they are injected into constructor that is no longer the case.
2. To quickly fix current code you can do the following. You have this code line:

   ```
   IRequiredService SomeService => StaticKernelReference.Get<IRequiredService>();
   ```

   First delete all stuff after name:

   ```
   IRequiredService SomeService;
   ```

   That will make your property a private field. Then alt-enter and use "Initialize field from constructor" refactoring. Then you have this:

   ```
   IRequiredService Service;
   public A(IRequiredService service) {
       Service = service;
   }
   ```

   Then continue with alt-enter "Rename to _service" (depends on how you name your private fields), then again alt-enter and "make field readonly".

   ```
   readonly IRequiredService _service;
   public A(IRequiredService service) {
       _service = service;
   }
   ```

Comment: Fantastic, your answer to part 2 is exactly the kind of thing I was hoping existed. This just saved me a ton of manual effort and should make this process a bit less painful, thank you!

Glad to hear the approach is appropriate as well. Your answer is much appreciated.